# Getting entry from db "0.00005" but showing in front end as "5.0E-5"

Tags: php

As the title says i'm getting this entry from database which is "0.0005" but showing as "5.0E-5" in frontend!

The query that get's the value from db

```
$totalValue = (float)$db->getValue("SELECT SUM(value_amount) AS total FROM value_detail WHERE user_id = " . (int) $Auth->id . " AND status IN ('pending', 'cleared')");
```

Then I echo `$totalValue`

Comment: a) this is not a sql concern, purely PHP. b) You're going to need to provide a sample of your PHP code so that someone can help you out.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I added the query.

Comment: The SQL query isn't the issue, the issue is in how you are displaying it via PHP. As far as the SQL query and the `$totalValue` variable is concerned, you just have a floating point number. The echo will be formatting it in scientific notation.

Comment: What if you don't typecast the value (ie remove `(float)`)?

Comment: You may want to look into how PHP formats floating-point numbers. This function may help, but I haven't experimented with it: https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/number_format.php

Answer (score 0):

The database is returning the value as a number (presumably a floating point or numeric value).  Something on the application side is controlling how that gets represented and deciding that exponential (or scientific) format is best.

SQL does not really let you control the representation.  However, it does allow you to convert the value to a string.  So, you *could* convert the value to a string representation using `format()`:

```
format(0.0005, 4)
```

Because this is a string, the downstream application should not be converting this to exponential format.